# Displaying reference property's variable through form

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

**models.py**

```
class User(db.Model):  
    user_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    nickname = db.StringProperty(required=False)  
    email = db.StringProperty(required=False)  
    pic_url = db.StringProperty(required=False)  
    type_admin = db.BooleanProperty(default=False)  

    school = db.ReferenceProperty(School, collection_name='user_school')

class School(db.Model):  
    school_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    school_name= db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    school_domain = db.StringProperty(required=False)
```

**views.py**

```
 uform = UserForm(instance=user)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(djangoforms.ModelForm):  
    class Meta:  
        model = User  
        exclude = ['user_id']
```

**html page**

```
{{ uform.school }}
```

This returns me a list of the school object in a dropdownlist. However, i want the `school_name` displayed in the dropdownlist.
How do i do that?

Comment: hey sorry i have no idea. new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override the `__unicode__` method on your School model

```
class School(db.Model):  
    school_id = db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    school_name= db.StringProperty(required=True)  
    school_domain = db.StringProperty(required=False) 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.school_name
```

Comment: @Lynn Chang: Thanks are nice.  Accepting the answer, however, is what makes the site/community work.